# Button not responding XML issue?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-button

I was working yesterday and not today. Have two buttons one to go back, one that is an emergency button that calls a method to open the dialer for a call to the ambulance. 
I think it may be an XML problem not sure was working fine now unresponsive maybe I changed something I shouldn't have. When it was clicking earlier it was saying the method could not be found which I just don't get it as it is in the correct file

ReportActivity.java

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //allows for a smoother transition
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);
        EditText incidentReport = this.findViewById(R.id.Incident_Report);
        incidentReport.setSelection(0);


    try {
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ReportActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error,", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    try {
        emergency.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(@NonNull View v) {
                Intent call = new Intent(ReportActivity.this, CallActivity.class);
                startActivity(call);

            }
        });
    } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error,", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
private boolean checkPermission(String permission) {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    return (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

public void call(View view) {
    if (checkPermission("android.permission.CALL_PHONE")) {
        Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        String number = "tel:" + getString(R.string.phone_number);
        call.setData(Uri.parse(number));
        startActivity(call);
    }
}
}
```

activity_report.xml

```
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="@string/Hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/submit_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yes_button"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Incident_Report" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/diagnose_button"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Back"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Incident_Report" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/emergency_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="131dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
        android:background="@drawable/no_button"
        android:onClick="call"
        android:text="EMERGENCY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/submit_btn" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You forgot to do `findViewById()`s for the `Button`s, like you did for the `EditText`, so the `setOnClickListener()` calls are throwing `NullPointerException`s. Your `Toast`s aren't showing the `catch` blocks because you forgot to `show()` them.

Comment: Thanks so much, thats exactly it had it written somewhere else but forgot to add those findViews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan on using `android:onClick="call"`in your xml then you should also have a corresponding function called `call`in your activity and the logic to perform the click goes inside it.

If you plan on extending the `View.onClickListener` then inside your `override void onClick()` you can have a switch statement of your button ids and perform your logic

alternatively you can ignore the first two and get the id of the button and implement the click logic inside the `onCreate()`